# How to make permanent data in java?

Tags: java

I am making a game with save files, so I need to make permanent data. It can not disappear when java closes. Searching for answer brings pages saying to use the properties class, but the documentation for the class suggests it does not store data permanently, or to download some class. However, I want to learn how to do this without downloading classes, just using java. How do I make permanent data?

Comment: persist it to database, file io, or some persistent caching mechanism based on your scenario

Comment: If it's small stuff you want to store, you could just use java's built in file io.

Comment: `Properties#load` and `Properties#store` allow you read/write the `Properties`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568147/saving-loading-data/18570090#18570090). You could also have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556932/how-to-save-the-state-of-my-minesweeper-game-and-then-load-it/19557052#19557052) which discuesses a number of possible solutions

Comment: One way or another you've got to write to a file.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of possible options available to you based on overall needs.

As for `Properties`, you could use one of the [`Properties#load`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.InputStream)) methods to load previously saved properties and [`Properties#store`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) to save them.

You could also have a look at [How can I save the state of my program and then load it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556932/how-to-save-the-state-of-my-minesweeper-game-and-then-load-it/19557052#19557052) which discuess a number of possibilities

Comment: if I use properties where to put my .txt file that stores the info? I copy and pasted code that uses properties but it can not find my .txt file. also, I am using intellij if that affects anything.

Comment: The file I'll be stored relative to the location that the program was executed from, most likely somewhere around the project location

Comment: You could store the configuration in the user.home directory, typically under windows this done using {user.home}/.{app name} or user.home}/AppData/local/{app name}. See a System.getProperty("user.home") to get the users home directory path

Answer (score 0):

You should either store it in files (using [JSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)/xml) or you can store it in MySQL database for quick and easy access. If it is something like player data or maps, use files. but if it is something like multiplayer small server data, i recommend to use MySQL. For storing permanent data in files, use Gson library

Answer (score 0):

if you are using java then I am sure you have object's and want to save them.

You can use **java.io.ObjectOutputStream** class to write your objects to any stream. using this you can write your objects to files and load it later.

preferred Do not forgot your object class to implement **Serializable** interface and giver serialVersionId, it will make sure your object to be serialized and de-serialized in same manner properly.

Comment: Object serialization is meant for the short term storage of objects, typically for transmission across the wire. It makes for a poor choice for long term storage, as it it's to easy for the data to out of date if the object it was based on is changed, especially when you condiser all the other possible choices